# Как в HashMap задать значение ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-hashmap

Есть `HashMap`, в котором ключу соответствует `ArrayList`. Например:
фрукты: яблоки, апельсины, груши;
овощи : картофель и морковь.

`hm` уже объявлен и мне необходимо сказать, что если попалась пара "фрукты - яблоки", то записать ее, если потом попалась пара "фрукты - груши", то записать груши к яблокам.

Как это сделать? Пишу на Java 7.

Comment: если перейдете на 8, то можно будет немного сократить код.

Answer (score 3):

Если по данному ключу нет списка, то создавать список для данного ключа. Затем добавлять новую еду в список, полученный по ключу:

```
private static final HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Food>> typeToFood = new HashMap<>();

private static void add(int type, Food food)
{
    if (!typeToFood.containsKey(type))
    {
        typeToFood.put(type, new ArrayList<Food>());
    }
    typeToFood.get(type).add(food);
}
```

Полный пример:

```
private static class Food
{
    public final String name;

    public Food(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

private static final int
        FRUIT = 1,
        VEGETABLE = 2;

private static final HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Food>> typeToFood = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    add(FRUIT, new Food("apple"));
    add(FRUIT, new Food("orange"));
    add(VEGETABLE, new Food("potato"));
    add(VEGETABLE, new Food("carrot"));
    for (int type : typeToFood.keySet())
    {
        for (Food food : typeToFood.get(type))
        {
            System.out.print(food.name + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static void add(int type, Food food)
{
    if (!typeToFood.containsKey(type))
    {
        typeToFood.put(type, new ArrayList<Food>());
    }
    typeToFood.get(type).add(food);
}
```

---

При использовании Java 8 метод `add` можно укоротить. Например, так:

```
private static void add(int type, Food food)
{
    typeToFood.putIfAbsent(type, new ArrayList<>());
    typeToFood.get(type).add(food);
}
```